# Filter MYSQL where multiple fields can match URL PARAMETER. IN, LIKE or REGEXP?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, url-parameters

i've created a page that displays all of the table results in a list, but if you select a category name, then it filters those results to all rows that match the category name in the URL(using friendly URL's) in either the `category_1` field or the `category_2` field. here's what i have now:

```
$colname_rs_categories = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['cat'])) {
    $colname_rs_categories = $_GET['cat'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_neonnettle, $neonnettle);

$query_rs_categories = sprintf("
     SELECT videos_id, 
         DATE_FORMAT(date,'%%D %%M %%Y @ %%l.%%i  %%p')date, 
         thumb, 
         title, 
         sub_title 
     FROM VIDEOS_view 
     WHERE %s IN (category_1, category_2) 
     ORDER BY videos_id DESC", 
     GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_categories, "text")
);

$query_limit_rs_categories = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_rs_categories, $startRow_rs_categories, $maxRows_rs_categories);
$rs_categories = mysql_query($query_limit_rs_categories, $neonnettle) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_categories = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_categories);
```

Now this has worked great up to a point. for example: if the users selects the category `"Pop"`, then the URL will be `www.example.com/pop` and it will list all the results that match either `category_1` and/or `category_2` with `"Pop"`.

The problem that i have is that if the category name is `"Pop Music"`, then the URL will be `www.example.com/pop-music` and this will then stop the results from being filtered as it no longer sees a match.

I have been experimenting with `LIKE` and `REGEXP` but i've had no luck. I was thinking something like this (but not this as it doesn't work):

```
WHERE (category_1 REGEXP '%s' OR category_2 REGEXP '%s')
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: i have now solved this by using REPLACE. here's what i did:

Comment: WHERE %s IN (REPLACE( category_1, ' ', '-' ), REPLACE( category_2, ' ', '-' ))